# Фильтр на два поля vue js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js

Не могу понять, как сделать фильтр массива ( в котором есть объекты )
Фильтровать можно по двум параметрам
Скриншоты:
[link](https://monosnap.com/file/bePsb8aXXczypQwf4ISw9pwLz6wuiQ)

Comment: [mcve]? И уж точно не скриншотом. И не на внешнем сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто два фильтра последовательно к данным применяете:

```
computed: {
  filteredFruits: function() {
    return this.fruits
      .filter(/* фильтруем по имени*/)
      .filter(/* фильтруем по terminal*/)
  }
}
```

Comment: А не проще два условия в одно объединить? И лишний раз не перебирать массив

Comment: Типа так - `this.fruits.filter(el => el.terminal.match('ололо') && el.name.match('трололо'))`. Работать будет в два раза быстрей

Comment: Можно, тут всегда выбор: либо комбайн, либо функция делающее что-то одно, зависит от планируемого использования. Если фильтров много и они могут использоваться в различных сочетаниях, то лучше каждый фильтр под свою задачу, если что-то простое, то комбайн, имхо.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! А как быть, если в terminal будет еще массив?
fruits: [ {name: 'Apple', country:  ['Brazil', 'Russia'] }...]

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, просто фильтруете, используя ваши данные с нужными условиями.

Comment: Терминал фильтрует только тогда, когда в нем не массив (

Comment: `this.fruits.filter(el => el.terminal.indexOf(this.filterTerminals) > -1)`

Comment: Работает. Но теперь список не виден, пока я не начну вводить значение в инпут терминала

Comment: Справился с задачей ! Большое спасибо!!!